# Something is broken with system comments with JSON and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

I have encountered an issue using databased JSON files and PHP. I include a script called messages.php, and it operates using a GET id ref. It:

- opens a database connection,
- queries the row and column of the current article,
- decodes the json data with php_decode(),
- and writes the results to the page.

I think something is broken in the JSON handling. The JSON validated through one with a link posted on a related question.

Here's some code:

```
<?php

//Prepare a database query, searching for messages
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id =".$_GET['id']." LIMIT 1";
echo "<script>alert($query);</script>";

//Create a connection
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','empty_user','tough_pass','roadsidediner_menu');

//Provide a query and handle
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

//Aquire the article row
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo $row;

//Store the json data
$rough_json = $row['comments'];

//decode the json file
$json = json_decode($rough_jason,true); //????
var_dump[$json]; //NEVER GETS TO THE VAR DUMP

    $html = "<div class='comment'>";
    $html .= "<h5> said on ";
    $html .= "</h5>";
    $html .= "<p></p></div>";
    echo $html;

$mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

These are the known issues: the php script stops midway through the main.php. This is happening somewhere in the above code, maybe with my JSON? Here's that:

```
{
"comments": [
{ "name":"Jon" , 
  "lastName":"Bucks" , 
  "thedate":"May 1, 2013" , 
  "message":"message test one"
},
{ "name":"Joe" , 
"lastName":"Buick" , 
"thedate":"June 6, 2013" , 
"message":"message test two"
},
{ "name":"Jack" , 
"lastName":"Brick" , 
"thedate":"December 2, 2013" , 
"message":"message test three"}
]
}
```

How'd you do it?

Comment: So where is your script actually halting?  Have you done any debugging to narrow it down? Are you getting any errors in your logs?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your `SELECT` statement. Also, `var_dump[$json]` isn't going to work - you need round brackets, not square ones. And `$mysqli_close($con);` won't work either - here you are running a variable-named method, rather than the database call you believe you are making `:)`.

Comment: You have several typos in your code, already mentioned in the previous comments. Maybe the one originating your problem is you're trying to decode `$rough_jason` instead of `$rough_json`.

Comment: you guys pinned it.

It was the json_decode($wrongvariable) causing the script to stop. WOrking fine now thx i do php/json/mysql now :-)

Comment: You need to turn on error reporting in your environment - you can reset this in your code, or in php.ini.